# Setting TEXTAREA and INPUT fields to 100% width inside TD truncates right margin

Tags: html, css, html-table

Please help me fix this issue. I would like to set the width of INPUT and TEXTAREA elements to 100% so that they entirely fit the table cell but I noticed that the right border is truncated.

I tried to wrap the INPUT inside a DIV and set 'overflow' to 'hidden' as I read on other answers but it does not work:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden">
    <input class="input_field" type="text" />
</div>
```

I also set margins and paddings, and width=95% too but the right border is always truncated even if it is well inside the TD.

Please see the [HTML and CSS code at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trwut/2/). Look carefully to the right border of the elements, you will see they are truncated. Set 'table border=0' to see better.

Comment: I would like to explain you the reason of the answers below (they are just working code, but maybe you can't understand where's the problem with your code). The border is truncated because *100%* is referred to element width excluding borders. So, your inputs are, in fact, *100% + 2px + 2px* large.

Comment: @lorenzo-s is correct. For an even fuller explanation see the link I included in the bottom of my answer. It explains the whole thing in detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `box-sizing: border-box` (and the corresponding browser-specific versions):

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/trwut/4/

Related reading: http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Comment: The non-prefixed version should follow the vendor-prefixed versions, so the final implementation overrides the 'beta' implementations.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS specification states that the width of an element does not include the border; which could be argued as wrong and complicates the width in scenarios like yours.

Funnily enough, Internet Explorer went against this CSS specification and used what was known as the box model (width including the border) - which caused a headache at the time, but can now be applied to other browsers using the following CSS:

```
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

To support my answer (as the upvote was removed), you can read the following article:

[Revenge of the IE Box Model](http://www.jefftk.com/news/2012-02-18.html) by Jeff Kaufman

Comment: Any chance of an explanation for the removal of the up-vote? I would like to understand where my answer is wrong and improve it.

Comment: You should include "-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;" for mobile browser support.

Comment: (Note that I didn't upvote you or remove an upvote; I posted another answer altogether. Just pointing out that you should also include the webkit prefix -- otherwise your answer is correct)

Comment: @BenLee Thanks, I have updated my answer to include the webkit support. I did see your answer so I did not think it would have been you. I thought I had been down-voted at first, but then I saw the up-voter had cancelled their vote so maybe they just meant to vote on yours and hit mine by mistake.

Comment: I don't deserve an upvote any more than you do. I upvoted you to compensate for whoever removed your upvote before =).